# CSP Blocking images from S3

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a client that uploads an image to the server, then, the server takes that image and uploads it to S3, waits for the URL and then return the URL for that image.

The problem is that for some reason, the client refuses to load the image provided by the server

In the console this is the message that I get (removed actual URL for privacy reasons):
*Refused to load the image '**URL**' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".*

The image is uploaded with all read permissions, so anyone can read the url.

The CSP in the HTML is like this:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src * 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">`

I must say that I'm passing to the client the URL that was created by amazon. eg:

`https://mybucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ecc6898f-56b1-4ad1-bb73-3b5c9749d264.jpeg`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the wildcard is being ignored when there are other entries in the directive

So try this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src https 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

Comment: Didn't work, still having the exact same behaviour.

Comment: Is this bit still the same? "...because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:"

Comment: Yeah, I got it fixed. It was Spring Security messing around, overriding the CSP. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. All's well that end's well.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed.

This angular app was running on a server that was also running a Java Springboot with Spring Security.

Spring security has a configuration function that override the HTTP behaviour of the server (URIs removed from example for security reasons::

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
        .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
    .and()
        .headers()
        .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:")
    .and()
        .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN)
    .and()
        .featurePolicy("geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; speaker 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; payment 'none'")
    .and()
        .frameOptions()
        .deny()
    .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/endpoint").permitAll()
        .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());
    // @formatter:on
}
```